# mysql last record of one column with sums of others and group by

Tags: mysql, sum, greatest-n-per-group

Table is like this:

```
id ||    name    ||  team    ||  goals  ||  data
1  ||    Kitten  || Pets     ||  3      ||  12
2   ||   Dog     ||  Pets    ||  2      ||  11
3   ||  Kitten   || Animals  ||  5      ||   6
4   ||  Kitten   || Cats     ||  4      ||   3
5   ||  Dog      ||  Pets    ||  2      ||   9
```

My basic query is:
SELECT name, team, SUM(goals), SUM(data) FROM table GROUP BY name

Results are like:

```
name    ||  team ||  sum(goals) ||  sum(data)
Kitten  || Pets  ||    12       ||   21
Dog     || Pets  ||     4       ||   20
```

I want to be able to get the most recent team (the highest id), but so far all I've been able to get is the first team listed with the query as written. I can get the first or last team alphabetically by using min(team) or max(team), but that doesn't always give the last record that I need. Help? Also, sorry I don't know how to format things well here.

Comment: your question is a little bit confusing, do you want to get the `SUM` of `goals` and `data` and the highest `ID`? if so, you can use `SELECT MAX(id), name, team, SUM(goals), SUM(data)...`

Comment: To maintain formatting, paste your text in, mark it with the mouse, and then use `{}` or `Ctl-k` to mark it as code. Just make sure you don't use TAB in the original text, because SO's tab stops are probably different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing this, but here is one.

You can get the most recent record for each team like this:

```
select * from table where id in(select max(id) from table group by team)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're asking for:

```
SELECT name, team, SUM(goals), SUM(data)
FROM table t1
JOIN (SELECT team
      FROM table
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 1) t2
ON t1.team = t2.team
GROUP BY name
```